# Verbatim doesn't follow tab alignment after changing font

Tags: fonts, verbatim

I searched online to find a way to match the verbatim font with the outside text. And this is what I used.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{\def\verbatim@font{#1}}%
\makeatother

\verbatimfont{\rmfamily}
\begin{verbatim}
L                                                           = 788 mm
E (Young's Modulus)                                         = 210000 N/mm
t (thickness)                                               = 8 mm
a (distance of furthest edge)                               = 4 mm
\end{verbatim}
```

Ordinarily this would print the text as is in the proper alignment. But if I change the font, as I have, to \rmfamily the alignment is compromised for some reason. (I use tabs for the spacing)

[image: Compiler output]

Comment: sorry but what do you expect? You are now using a font where every letter has a different width. Why do you use verbatim instead of e.g. a tabular to align your text?

Comment: there is no reason at all why anything should line up if you use `\rmfamily`. That is why mnonospace fonts are called monospace: all the characters are the same width.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for letting me know. I am currently usign listings to have a single font for the entire document.

Comment: but the output you show just seems to be a table it is not verbatim code so why are you using listings or verbatim at all???, just use `tabular` and mark the alignment points with `&`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Started using latex yesterday. Probably why. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a display would normally be aligned using `tabular` or related constructs, with alignment points marked with `&`. `verbatim` (and even `listings`) are designed for things like code blocks (as on this site) where there is no explicit alignment but alignment is automatic as all characters have the same width.

I show `tabular` here. You could also consider using a specific package such as `siunitx` to get consistent display of units but that is a separate issue not covered here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{flushleft}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
L &                               &=& 788 mm \\
E & (Young's Modulus)             &=& 210000 N/mm \\
t & (thickness)                   &=& 8 mm \\
a & (distance of furthest edge)   &=& 4 mm \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this !

Comment: Can you explain what kind of a modifier {@{}llll@{}} is?

Comment: Nevermind, I found what seems like a comprehensive guide on the tabular environment. It does seem to cover modifiers. Thanks again!

Comment: Is \begin{flushleft} necessary here or is it a good habit to have? I don't see it affecting the output in any way. What situations would call for using this?

Comment: @Wren it sets the table flush to the left margin (you might prefer `\begin{center}`) and adds some vertical space before and after